# How to query two tables to compare data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to compare some data in SQL Server (2005). I have two tables and I need to make sure that the values from table 1 are matched in table two. Here's the table structure and some example data.

```
Table 1 
GenreId
6
```

This is a temp table with a list of IDs that are passed in.

```
Table 2
Show| GenreId
Show1 | 2
Show1 | 6
Show2 | 6
```

This table can have many GenreIds for a show. The results that I am trying to figure out how to retrieve are that I only need shows that only have the GenreIds from table 1. So the results I expect in the end would be:

If table 1 has 6, I expect to ONLY get Show2. If table 1 has 2 and 6, then I get Show1 and Show2.

I know this is probably simple but I am really drawing a blank. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why for 6 only Show2 should be selected?

Comment: In this case, if more than one genre exists the show has to match all of the ones provided. It was hard to illustrate with sample data.

Comment: With 2 and 6 in Table1 Show2 will not match criteria _match all of the ones provided_ and hence only Show1 should be taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT SHOW FROM t2
WHERE SHOW NOT IN (
  SELECT SHOW FROM t2
  WHERE genreId NOT IN (6, 2)
)
GROUP BY SHOW
HAVING count(DISTINCT genreId) = 2
```

Those queries are a bit tricky. Take into account that the number in the `HAVING` clause have to match the AMOUNT of items in the `IN` clause.

Now, provided that you have a table that contains those IDs, then you can solve it this way:

```
SELECT SHOW FROM t2
WHERE SHOW NOT IN (
  SELECT SHOW FROM t2
  WHERE genreId NOT IN (
    SELECT genreId FROM t1
  )
)
GROUP BY SHOW
HAVING count(DISTINCT genreId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f42f0/1).

Comment: This is the query that works in all the cases I've tried so far. When I actually plugged things in with my real data some of the others came very close but a few edge cases gave wrong results. Thanks a lot for the help. I spent hours with this today trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this should work but it may have horrible performance if `Table2` is large...

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT GenreID 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE GenreID NOT IN (
        SELECT GenreID 
        FROM Table2 
        WHERE Show = t2.Show))
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT GenreID 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE GenreID NOT IN (
        SELECT GenreID FROM Table1)
    AND Show = t2.Show)
```

Comment: This works but you're missing the `S` from exists and a bracket at then end of the first `EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

> If table 1 has 6, I expect to ONLY get Show2. If table 1 has 2 and 6,
>   then I get Show1 and Show2.

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c5dc/1)** (Demo is on Sql Server 2012 but query should work on 2005):

```
select Max([show]) myShow
from T2 join T1
      on T2.GenreId = T1.GenreId
Group by T2.GenreId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Show from Table2
inner join Table1
on Table1.GenreId = Table2.GenreId
```

Comment: Actually don't.  It's an inner join.  You're only going to return rows where GenreId meets the join criteria on both sides.

Comment: I think I answered it in an above post now.

select Show from Table2
where genreid in (select genreid from Table1)
except
select Show from Table2
where genreid not in (select Genreid from Table1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. It checks if the show is the only show for the selected genre.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Show FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.GenreId = Table2.GenreId
AND (SELECT Count(DISTINCT GenreId) FROM Table2 T2 WHERE Table2.Show = T2.Show) = 1
```

Comment: `If table 1 has 6, I expect to ONLY get Show2` this is not the answer

Comment: I haven't tested this but the only way I know to make sure that ALL and ONLY ALL elements match a set is a double negation... and I just don't see it here. So I have to assume that you might be adding some elements that you actually shouldn't.

Comment: @MostyMostacho So please test it before making comments. The question was about a show being the only genre. So I'm checking if count(genreid) = 1, where's the need for double negation?

Comment: If you don't want my comments then don't ask me to check your edit. I won't test your query either. I've provided a fiddle that you can use to test it yourself.

Comment: "Check edit" comment was to the person asking question as my first answer was not correct. Used your fiddle, my query works.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  I understand what you're asking now, I think.

This?

```
select Show from Table2
where genreid in (select genreid from Table1)
except
select Show from Table2
where genreid not in (select Genreid from Table1)
```